# Get position of object in opengl after transforms

Tags: java, opengl, transform, lwjgl

I would like to get the coordinates of an object in OpenGL. I draw a quad. And after that I do some transforms like GL11.glTranslatef() and GL11.glRotatef().

```
GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS); // draw independent triangles
GL11.glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
GL11.glVertex3f(-0.2f, 0.0f, -2.0f);    // lower left vertex
GL11.glVertex3f( 0.2f, 0.0f, -2.0f);    // upper vertex
GL11.glVertex3f( 0.2f, 0.4f, -2.0f);    // lower right verte
GL11.glVertex3f( -0.2f, 0.4f, -2.0f);
GL11.glEnd();
```

Is it possible to get the position of the vertices after the transformation?

Comment: Which position do you mean? The position transformed by modelview or the screen position if the vertices (so transform by modelview and perspective matrix)? I don't know to much about the java ogl bindings, but there might be something like `gluProject` for that. Furthermore if the binding maps directly to opengl functions note that in modern opengl matrixoperations (glTranslate/glRotate) and immediate mode (glBegin/glVertex/glEnd) are deprecated, so looking at other ways to do that might be worthwile anyways

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. Apply the same transforms (translations and rotations) to a position vector, that holds the position of your object. The result will be the position of your object after the transform. You may need to do some scaling at some point if you want to convert the 3d co-ords to 2d screen co-ords. But this is very much doable. It involves scaling based on the z-depth of the object.

EDIT:

```
 private final FloatBuffer buffer = EngineUtil.createBuffer( 16 );

      /**
    * @return Current modelview matrix (column-major)
    */
   public Matrix getModelviewMatrix() {
      return getMatrix( GL11.GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX );
   }

   /**
    * @return Current projection matrix (column-major)
    */
   public Matrix getProjectionMatrix() {
      return getMatrix( GL11.GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX );
   }

   /**
    * Retrieves the specified matrix.
    * @param name Matrix name
    */
   private Matrix getMatrix( int name ) {
      // Retrieve specified matrix buffer
      buffer.rewind();
      GL11.glGetFloat( name, buffer );

      // Convert to array
      final float[] array = new float[ 16 ];
      buffer.get( array );

      // Convert to matrix
      return new Matrix( array );
   }
```

But you may want to simply use something more complete than LWJGL. Google vecmath, processing, unity. 3D is tricky and it seems there are no real short cuts, so just keep trying, you will get it.

Comment: Do you know how to program translation or rotation on a vector of vertices in opengl with lwjgl? All I need is the positions in the modelview matrix?;

Comment: Translation is easy,you just add the x,y,z co-ords respectively. Rotation you need to multiply R x V where R is your rotation matrix, V is your position vector. There's a static method http://lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/util/vector/Matrix4f.html here called transform. You put in your rotation matrix, and your original and target vectors.

Comment: thanks for the help, but I still dont know how to get the rotation matrix?

Answer (score 0):

this is not possible... opengl sends your vertex data to the GPU and only on GPU you can get them after the transformation.

to get transformed vertices you have to multiply them by the matrix

```
for each vertex:
   vertex_transformed = matrix * vertex
```

some more advanced ways is to use **transform feedback** and store those transformed vertices into a buffer (but still this buffer will be stored on the GPU).